# Javascript - Typing game with pics

Tags: javascript

Now i'm trying to create a vocabulary leaning game with pics.
The game is so: when you type the word with that tips by pics correctly, then comes new set of the word and pic. I set the set of vocabulary and pics and let them to show random, but even if i type the word correctly, it doesn't change into new word & pic. The Code of javascript is here:

```
'use strict';

{
  const question = document.getElementById('js-image');
  const target = document.getElementById('js-target');
  const quizSet = shuffle([
    {q: '../img/***1.png', t:'***1'}, // q: pics, t: words
    {q: '../img/***2.png', t:'***2'},
    {q: '../img/***3.png', t:'***3'},
    {q: '../img/***4.png', t:'***4'},
    {q: '../img/***5.png', t:'***5'},
    {q: '../img/***6.png', t:'***6'},
  ]);

  let currentNum = 0;
  let loc = 0;
  let isPlaying = false;
  let word = quizSet[currentNum].t;
  let image =  quizSet[currentNum].q;

   function shuffle(arr) {
       for (let i = arr.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
         const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
         [arr[j], arr[i]] = [arr[i], arr[j]];
       }
       return arr;
     }

  function setQuiz(){
    question.src = image;
    target.textContent = word;
    loc = 0;
    word = 0;
    image = 0;
    }

    document.addEventListener('click', ()=> {
    if (isPlaying === true){
      return;
    }

    isPlaying = true;
    setQuiz();
  });

   document.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
     if (e.key !== word[loc]) {
       return;
     }
     loc++;
     target.textContent = '_'.repeat(loc) + word.substring(loc);

    if (loc === word.length){
      setQuiz();
      }
   });
 }
```

What is the problem? Thank you for your help and kindness!